# Image slide using OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Lets say I have a stack of bitmap textures

```
char *Texture[] =
{ 
  "texture1.bmp",
  "texture2.bmp",
  "texture3.bmp",
  "texture4.bmp",
}
```

and I want to use all the pictures using some function in which they will be processed and displayed by some trigger, each one at a time. Do you know if there is any openGL function for implementing this scenario?

Comment: Yes I know, there isn't!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenGL is not a scene graph.  It's just a fancy triangle rasterization system.  [See here](http://memegenerator.net/instance/9519571).

Image loading, animation, and triggers are all (much) higher-level pieces of functionality *not* provided by OpenGL.

Comment: Thank you on your reply. However, as you know there are so many libraries for OpenGL system, and many of them deal with the image loading, animation and triggers etc., so after all it's not just fancy triangle rasterization system. Is it possible for you to know some of them, 'cause I am beginner in OpenGL programming, and all the references are important to me, especially including the reference that will solve this issue.

Comment: @DzekTrek: Having libraries built on top of something doesn't change what that something is. It simply means that there are suplimental libraries out there. Those libraries are built on top of OpenGL; they are not *part* of OpenGL.

Comment: @NicolBolas +100. Sorry for my stupid comment, but somebody just has to emphasize yours beyond upvoting!